# Apache run script when no requests

Tags: php, bash, apache

I would like to know if there is a way to trigger a bash or php script when my webserver (apache and php) has no traffic since 10min for example.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could poll the access logs once every minute with a script in cron, and check if the last entry was more than ten minutes ago. If it was, do what you need to do.

Check the output of `tail -n1 /path/to/access/log`, parse it and check the time against current time.

Comment: That won't work if the web server is behind a load balancer that does periodic health checks.

Comment: It could be modified to ignore those entries if that turns out to be the case.

Comment: this solution perfectly suits my needs. I don't use load balancer.